# How to make dropdownlist required in angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-material, dropdown

I have a search 'form' with  angular material.  But it is not a form with a submit button. But just a button. like this:

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="Button" (click)="searchFor()">Filter</button>
```

and I have a dropdownlist. But I want to make the dropdownlist required.

Like this:

```
 <div class="search-select searchstatus" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasStatusOptions(selectedSearch)">
        <mat-select placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getStatusOptions(selectedSearch)"  [value]="option.apiStatus">
            {{ option.status }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
```

But his doesnt work.

So how to make the dropdownlist required? Thank you

For datepicker it works. If I do this:

```
   <input matInput readonly required [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="start datum" [(ngModel)]="startDate" />
```

Then if there is no date entered the label becomes red and there is showing a *

if I do this:

```
   <mat-select  #statusSelect placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [required]="true" >
```

and this:

```
   <button [disabled] = '!statusSelect.value' mat-raised-button color="accent" class="Button" (click)="searchFor()">Filter</button>
```

I get this error:

```
ExtendedSearchComponent.html:62 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing from the information provided that you want to select a value from the dropdown and filter based on that. So, you can disable the filter till a value is selected in the dropdown. Maybe something like this.

```
<div>
    <mat-select placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" required>
       <mat-option></mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let option of tableDef"  [value]="option">
            {{ option.header }}
       </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
 </div>

<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="Button" (click)="searchFor()" [disabled]="!selectedValue">Filter</button>
```

Edit:-

I saw your comments above after the edit. Instead of using the css selector (#statusSelect.value), you can directly check by the object you are binding to the [(ngModel)] i.e "selectedValue"

Comment: Oke, thank you. But so can you use RactiveForm without type==submit? So just  (click)="searchFor()"

Comment: No problem. Always happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pretty close. The [API Section](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) for the *Select* component at the Angular Material page offers a `required: boolean` Input. Changing:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" required>
```

to

```
<mat-select placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [required]="true">
```

might be what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did that:   <mat-select placeholder="Status" name="option"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [required]="true"> But that doesnt work. I can still select the button filter without any message that the dropdown is required

Comment: Oh, I probably misunderstood. So you want to disable the button as long as required dropdowns don't have a selected value? If that's the case, you need to refer to answer from vadjs. And if you have multiple required dropdowns, you can probably just && the booleans? For example, `[disabled]="!select1.value && select2.value && ..."

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way is to make template-driven form.
But you can bind your dropdown to template reference variable without any `form` usage.

```html
<mat-select #yourSelect></mat-select>

<button [disabled]='!yourSelect.value'>Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have more dropdowns who are required.

Comment: If you need more than one dropdown required you can  add one more condition, like `<button [disabled]='!yourSelect.value || !yourAnotherSelect.value'>Button</button>`
But i strongly recommend to use form in this case.

Comment: oke, but maybe I think wrong. But with Forms I always think you have to submit the form. But this is just a search 'form' so without a submit

Comment: Submit button is not necessary. You can use form.value at any moment.
For example: you can use something like this: `form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => sendRequest(value))`, it will work every time when form value changes.